# React Hook form is being rendered before React.useEffect call is being completed on page rendering

Tags: react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to render particular user information on render of a page using the API call inside the  React.useEffect. On the same page, I have a React Hook form being used which sets the default values based on the API call from useEffect.

The issue is the React Hook form is being rendered first on page rendering and sets the user info to undefined and then only the React.useEffect call happens which sets the user info. This way it will always give me the default user values and not the values from the API call.

Here is the code

```
const [clients, setClients] = useState<Client>();
 
 React.useEffect(()=>{

      api.get<Client>('/clients/4').then(
        (response)=> {
          const clientResponse = response.data;
          setClients(clientResponse);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    },[]);

const methods = useForm<Client>({
    defaultValues: clients ? clients : defaultClientValues,
    reValidateMode: 'onChange',
    mode: 'onChange',
    validationSchema: clientSchema,
  });
```

On this, I'm always getting the clients as undefined in the defaultValues inside useForm method.

Also tried using React.useLayoutEffect() but it seems to give me the same sort of result.

Comment: That's expected. `By default, React runs the effects after every render — including the first render. ` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Comment: But why does the React useForm gets rendered first and then useEffect gets rendered. It should be like useEffect gets rendered first and then useForm should be rendered.

Comment: Did you manage to read the link I sent?

Comment: Yes I did manage to read that document. The issue is with React Hook form not getting updated on re-render.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now. Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `By default, React runs the effects after every render — including the first render`.

[React Hooks documentation](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)

If the child component is not getting the updated value, you can create another `hook`, and assign `clients` to a `ref` and update the `ref` each time `clients` value changes.

```
const clientsRef = React.useRef(defaultClientValues);

React.useEffect(() => {
  api.get<Client>('/clients/4').then(
    (response) => {
      const clientResponse = response.data;
      setClients(clientResponse);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  clientsRef.current = clients;
}, [clients);

const methods = useForm<Client>({
  defaultValues: clientsRef.current ? clientsRef.current : defaultClientValues,
  reValidateMode: 'onChange',
  mode: 'onChange',
  validationSchema: clientSchema,
});
```